# Load custom location list in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

In IntelliJ IDEA, when I press Alt-F7, it loads a list of usages of whatever I'm highlighting; it's a nice list feature that allows me to jump around various lines of code that are of interest.

I'm interested in doing that in a more abstract way. If I write a script that analyzes code and spits out a list of files and line numbers, I'd like to be able to navigate those in a similar fashion. Similar to Vim's quickfix feature (and I'm sure other text editors support this sort of thing).

Example output:

```
project-a/src/main/java/com/example/Foo.java:34
project-a/src/main/java/com/example/Foo.java:66
project-b/src/main/java/com/example/Bar.java:198
```

**Does IntelliJ support loading this as a list of locations?** If so, how?

The case in particular I have is that I wrote a script that looks for `throw` statements inside a `catch` block that do not reference the caught exception. So I can output the locations any way that IntelliJ likes to see them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up an external tool that will run your script, and configure an output filter to turn its output into clickable links. It won't look like the usages view, but it's the simplest thing you can do.

Alternatively, you can convert your script into an IntelliJ inspection, which will let you see its results directly as you're editing code, or run Analyze | Inspect Code to get a summary of the results across your project.

Comment: there is an existing inspection for this! " 'throw' inside 'catch' block which ignores the caught exception"